# How can I set up a complex model association in ExtJS 4?

Tags: database, model, extjs4

Here's the basic table structure in the database:

```
Users   <->   UserGroups   <->   Groups
```

Basically, a group can contain many users, and a user can be a part of many groups. The `UserGroups` table is just an association.

How can I represent this same relationship using ExtJS 4 models?

I'm thinking the properties need to be something like:

```
Users       belongsTo UserGroups
UserGroups  hasMany Users and Groups
Groups      belongsTo UserGroups
```

I'm just unsure if that will work as I need it to (since I will need to save the association between users and groups to the database).

I'm going to continue researching, but I hope either someone knows how to accomplish this, or at least has a good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple to do now, check this:

```
Ext.define('Group', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'user_id', 'group_id'],
    belongsTo: 'UserGroups'
});

Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'group_id'],
    belongsTo: 'UserGroup'
});


Ext.define('UserGroup', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'name'],

    hasMany  : [{model: 'User', name: 'users'},
                {model: 'Group', name: 'groups'}]
});
```

That should get you starting.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I ended up doing the opposite, so that UserGroup belongs to both User and Group. This allowed me to access data from UserGroup after clicking on a 'Group' record in a grid.

Comment: Great, glad to know you finally got a solution!